# How do I fix auto increment in oracle after a data refresh

Tags: sql, oracle, auto-increment

Every time my team does a data refresh to our UAT environment we have issues with the 'auto incremented' columns in oracle They hold onto the old value and therefore cause errors when a new insert happens. The only solution I have found is to use

select test_SEQ.nextval from test_table;

Until the next sequence is bigger then the max seq number in the table. I have over 200 tables to update, is there an easier why to do this?

Thanks
Erin

Comment: What are the details of the data refresh?

Comment: I have seen many references to this same issue on SO, so maybe do some searching.  How do you copy the data from one system to the other?

Answer (score 0):

One better way to do this would be to drop the sequences and create new ones with the desired START WITH value.  You could generate the DDL to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17345/1

It doesn't completely work due to limitations in sqlfiddle, but here's the function that makes it happen:

```
create or replace function 
reset_sequence(p_sequence_name varchar, 
               p_table_name varchar, 
               p_column_name varchar)
return integer is
v_temp integer;
v_sql varchar(2000);
begin
v_sql := 'select nvl(max('||p_column_name||'),0)+1 col_name from '||p_table_name;
execute immediate v_sql INTO v_temp;

  v_sql := 'drop sequence '||p_sequence_name;
  execute immediate v_sql;


v_sql := 'create sequence '||p_sequence_name||' start with '||v_temp;
execute immediate v_sql;

return v_temp;
end;
```

Basically you call this function and pass a schema name, table name and column name and it will set the function to the correct value. You can put a begin/exception/end block to ignore errors when dropping the sequence, in case it doesn't exist, but all that is just icing. You could also have it detect the column that is the primary key if you wanted, but no real way in Oracle to detect the sequence name.
You could also make a procedure version of this, but I tend to prefer functions for whatever reason.